# How to track page views in react using reach router and google analytics?

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, create-react-app, reach-router

I'm porting backbone app to React app. in backbone app I have the following snippet

```
    <!-- Begin UA code -->
    <script>
    window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
    ga('create', 'UA-xxx', 'auto');

    // Load plugins

    // Rewrite all GA pages with /ra_minisite prefix
    ga('require', 'cleanUrlTracker', {
      stripQuery: true,
      queryDimensionIndex: 1,
      urlFieldsFilter: function(fieldsObj, parseUrl) {
        fieldsObj.page = '/ra_minisite'+parseUrl(fieldsObj.page).pathname
        return fieldsObj;
      },
    });

    ga('require', 'eventTracker');
    ga('require', 'maxScrollTracker');

    // Customize so WS.com not tracked as outbound link
    ga('require', 'outboundLinkTracker');

    ga('require', 'socialWidgetTracker');
    ga('require', 'urlChangeTracker');

    // Commented out so we can call after all API calls are done
    // Called from metaManager
    // ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>
    <script async src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
    <script async src="/autotrack.js"></script>
    <!-- end UA code -->
```

And then on each page render after updating meta tags it calls

```
window.ga('send', 'pageview');
```

I assume I can just drop init logic into index.html, but what would be a nice, simple way to hook `window.ga('send', 'pageview');` into reach router, so that when route changes or updates, pageview would be sent to GA?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can listen to the global history object. In your `App.js`:

```
import { globalHistory } from '@reach/router';

globalHistory.listen(({ location }) => {
  window.ga('send', 'pageview');
  // or use the new gtag API
  window.gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', {'page_path': location.pathname});
});
```

This is the easiest way, with the least amount of code, and, unlike the `LocationProvider` method presented in the top answer, it doesn't break the global `navigate` API.

Unfortunately it appears `globalHistory` is not documented anywhere, so this was a hard find.

Comment: I used this concept with react-ga

```
globalHistory.listen(({ location }) => {
  ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can manually create the history object that you can listen to for changes with the `createHistory` function. You could attach a listener and send a `pageview` event there.

**Example**

```js
import { createHistory, LocationProvider } from '@reach/router';

const history = createHistory(window);

history.listen(() => {
  window.ga('send', 'pageview');
});

const App = () => (
  <LocationProvider history={history}>
    <Routes />
  </LocationProvider>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for giving it a shot. Tried your suggestion. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working, url changes but components don't and 'listen' hook doesn't get executed. Could you please expand example with routes?

Comment: @AndreiMotinga Did you add the `<LocationProvider history={history}>` to your code as well? Otherwise the topmost `Router` will use a separate `history` of its own.

Comment: @AndreiMotinga [Here is a very basic example](https://codesandbox.io/s/8k31jx84m9).

Comment: I believe it didn't work for me because of some divs between or around LocationProvider. In any case, this seems to work, only it seems to be breaking `navigate`, or maybe, componentDidUpdate. I didn't have any luck trying to reproduce with a simple example. In my code, however, url changes but componentDidUpdate doesn't get triggered. Do you have any idea why that might be? do I need to supply same history to `navigate` somehow?

Comment: Just chiming in that this breaks `navigate` for me as well (url changes but the components do not). I'll come back if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the location provider API from reach router:

```
import { Router,createHistory,LocationProvider }from "@reach/router";
import ReactGA from "react-ga";
ReactGA.initialize("UA-103xxxxx-xx");
const history= createHistory(window);
history.listen( window => {
  ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname+ window.location.search);
  console.log('page=>',window.location.pathname);
});
```

And then in use it in the route:

```
<LocationProvider history={history}>
  <Router></Router>
</LocationProvider>
```

[Here](https://link.medium.com/v8blVsugn4) is the complete solution.